# Initializing an array of Images

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 17 images on my application i created through the xaml in my WPF.  I'm trying to insert them into an array for easier coding

```
private static Image[] AllImageArr;

AllImageArr = new Image
                {
                    BluePick1_Image, BluePick2_Image, BluePick3_Image, BluePick4_Image, BluePick5_Image, 
                    RedPick1_Image, RedPick2_Image, RedPick3_Image, RedPick4_Image, RedPick5_Image, 
                    BlueBan1_Image, BlueBan2_Image, BlueBan3_Image, 
                    RedBan1_Image, RedBan2_Image, RedBan3_Image 
                };
```

but i'm getting a "Cannot initialize type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'" error.

how can i fix this?

Comment: gawd i'm dumb.  was stuck on that for an hour now.  sigh thank you. if you were to answer the question i'll give u credit

Comment: Preston is right but why don't you use a list instead ?

Comment: If you don't need list operations, why would you use a list?

Comment: can you give me an example in the answers?  give u an upvote for it. always good to know alternatives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, you need `new Image[] { /* stuff in collection */ }`

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing it properly. Use `Image[]`:

```
AllImageArr = new Image[]
                {
                    BluePick1_Image, BluePick2_Image, BluePick3_Image, BluePick4_Image, BluePick5_Image, 
                    RedPick1_Image, RedPick2_Image, RedPick3_Image, RedPick4_Image, RedPick5_Image, 
                    BlueBan1_Image, BlueBan2_Image, BlueBan3_Image, 
                    RedBan1_Image, RedBan2_Image, RedBan3_Image 
                };
```